# Visual Flow Creating Opportunity and set probability AND stagename

Tags: opportunity, visual-workflow, standard-objects

I have a visual flow that essentially generates a renewal of an already existing opportunity.  The flow is launched from a button on the opportunity.  I use the record create element to create the renewal opportunity.  One of the things I need to do if specify a stage of the renewal opportunity (5 - closing) and a probability (95%).  Both of these field values are hard-coded into the create record element.

The problem is that the probability is tied to the stagename.  For regular opportunities, the probability of an opporutnity in stage "5 - closing" is 75%.  I need it to be 95% on the renewal opportunity.  Even though I specify the probability to be 95 in the flow, it is still 75% on the opportunity after it is created.  I cannot add an update record element because there are validation rules that are applied after opportunity creation that would cause an error in the flow.

How do I either force the probability to update, regardless of the stagename or how can I prevent validation rules from firing when the updates are coming from a visual workflow?

Thanks!

Comment: Seems like a bug in flow, but Mikes solution is solid

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is create a workflow rule which will fire when it meets your Renewal Opportunity and 5-closing criteria.  In the action you do a field update on the Probability field and set the value to .95

Activate the workflow when done.

First test manually, not through flow and confirm it works.

Then test with flow.

Let me know if this answer helps.  Thanks!